# Method inside a method in Python

Tags: python

I have seen source code where more than one methods are called on an object eg `x.y().z()` Can someone please explain this to me, does this mean that `z()` is inside `y()` or what?

Comment: It means that `x.y()` returns an object that has a method `z`, which is then called. Think of it as `obj = x.y(); obj.z()`.

Comment: Answer: Everything in Python is an object.

Comment: You may want to google "method chaining" and you should find lots of info on it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun True but irrelevant, as such chaining can done in Java for example. Nobody ever says "Everything in Java is an object", as many things that are objects in Python aren't objects in Java (classes and methods for one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This calls the method `y()` on object `x`, then the method `z()` is called on the result of `y()` and that entire line is the result of method `z()`.

**For example**

`friendsFavePizzaToping = person.getBestFriend().getFavoritePizzaTopping()`

This would result in `friendsFavePizzaTopping` would be the person's best friend's favorite pizza topping.

**Important to note:** `getBestFriend()` must return an object that has the method `getFavoritePizzaTopping()`. If it does not, an `AttributeError` will be thrown.

Comment: I secretly don't know enough python to give an example with standard libraries, so I took some liberties.

Comment: In other words, `person.getBestFriend` returns an object that will be expected to support a `getFavoritePizzaTopping` method, or else an `AttributeError` will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Each method is evaluated in turn, left to right. Consider:

```
>>> s='HELLO'
>>> s.lower()
'hello'
>>> s='HELLO    '
>>> s.lower()
'hello    '
>>> s.lower().strip()
'hello'
>>> s.lower().strip().upper()
'HELLO'
>>> s.lower().strip().upper().replace('H', 'h')
'hELLO'
```

The requirement is that the object to the left in the chain has to have availability of the method on the right. Often that means that the objects are similar types -- or at least share compatible methods or an understood cast.

As an example, consider this class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    def m1(self):
        return Foo(self.name+'=>m1')
    def m2(self):
        return Foo(self.name+'=>m2')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(id(self), self.name)    
    def m3(self):
        return .25    #   return is no longer a Foo
```

Notice that as a type of immutable, each return from Foo is a new object (either a new Foo for m1, m2 or a new float). Now try those methods:

```
>>> foo
4463545376: init
>>> foo.m1()
4463545304: init=>m1
^^^^                     different object id
>>> foo
4463545376: init
^^^^                     foo still the same because you need to assign it to change
```

Now assign:

```
>>> foo=foo.m1().m2()
>>> foo
4464102576: init=>m1=>m2
```

Now use m3() and it will be a float; not a Foo anymore:

```
>>> foo=foo.m1().m2().m3()
>>> foo
.25
```

Now a float -- can't use foo methods anymore:

```
>>> foo.m1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'm1'
```

But you can use [float methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-float):

```
>>> foo.as_integer_ratio()
(1, 4)
```

Comment: This only works because `lower()`, `strip()`, `upper()`, and `replace()` all return a string. It is important to note that each method is called on the result of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of:

```
x.y().z()
```

You're almost always looking at immutable objects. Mutable objects don't return anything that would HAVE a function like that (for the most part, but I'm simplifying). For instance...

```
class x:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y_done = False
        self.z_done = False
    def y(self):
        new_x = x()
        new_x.y_done = True
        return new_x
    def z(self):
        new_x = x()
        new_x.z_done = True
        return new_x
```

You can see that each of `x.y` and `x.z` returns an `x` object. That object is used to make the consecutive call, e.g. in `x.y().z()`, `x.z` is not called on `x`, but on `x.y()`.

```
x.y().z() =>
    tmp = x.y()
    result = tmp.z()
```

In @dawg's excellent example, he's using strings (which are immutable in Python) whose methods return strings.

```
string = 'hello'
string.upper() # returns a NEW string with value "HELLO"
string.upper().replace("E","O") # returns a NEW string that's based off "HELLO"
string.upper().replace("E","O") + "W"
# "HOLLOW"
```

Comment: Just because an object is mutable doesn't mean its methods *always* return `None`; just the methods that actually *mutate* the object.

Comment: `"for the most part, but I'm simplifying"` But well-noted.

Answer (score 0):

`x.y().z()` means that the `x` object has the method y() and the result of `x.y()` object has the method `z()` . Now if you first want to apply the method `y()` on `x` and then on the result want to apply the `z()` method, you will write `x.y().z()`. This is like,

```
val = x.y()
result = val.z()
```

Example:

```
my_dict = {'key':'value'}
```

`my_dict` is a `dict` type object. `my_dict.get('key')` returns 'value' which is a `str` type object. now I can apply any method of `str` type object on it. which will be like,

```
my_dict.get('key').upper()
```

This will return 'VALUE'.

Comment: Not true. `my_dict = {'key','value'}; my_dict.get('key').upper()` is valid code, but a `dict` has no method `upper`.

Comment: My context was that `y()` and `z()` both are in `x` method.

Comment: My point is that your context is flawed. Object `x` need not have both methods `y` and `z`, only method `y`, and object `x.y()` need have method `z`

Answer (score 0):

The `.` "operator" is Python syntax for attribute access. `x.y` is (nearly) identical to

```
getattr(x, 'y')
```

so `x.y()` is (nearly) identical to

```
getattr(x, 'y')()
```

(I say "nearly identical" because it's possible to customize attribute access for a user-defined class. From here on out, I'll assume no such customization is done, and you can assume that `x.y` is in fact identical to `getattr(x, 'y')`.)

If the thing that `x.y()` returns has an attribute `z` such that

```
foo = getattr(x, 'y')
bar = getattr(foo(), 'z')
```

is legal, then you can chain the calls together without needing the name `foo` in the middle:

```
bar = getattr(getattr(x, 'y')(), 'z')
```

Converting back to dot notation gives you

```
bar = getattr(x.y(), 'z')
```

or simply

```
bar = x.y().z()
```

Answer (score -2):

That is (sometimes a sign of) bad code.

It violates [The law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Here is a quote from Wikipedia explaining what is meant:

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

Suppose you have a car, which itself has an engine:

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self):
    self._engine=None

  @property
  def engine(self):
      return self._engine

  @engine.setter
  def engine(self, value):
      self._engine = value


class Porsche_engine:
  def start(self):
    print("starting")
```

So if you make a new car and set the engine to *Porsche* you could do the following:

```
>>> from car import *
>>> c=Car()
>>> e=Porsche_engine()
>>> c.engine=e
>>> c.engine.start()
starting
```

If you are maing this call from an Object, it has not only knowledge of a `Car` object, but has too knowledge of `Engine`, which is bad design.

Additionally: if you do not know whether a `Car` has an engine, calling directly `start`

```
>>> c=Car()
>>> c.engine.start()
```

May result in an Error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Edit:
To avoid (further) misunterstandings and misreadings, from what I am saying.
There are two usages:

1) as I pointed out, Objects calling methods on other objects, returned from a third object is a violation of LoD. This is one way to read the question.

2) an exception to that is [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Python), which is **not bad design**.

And a better design would be, if the `Car` itself had a `start()`-Method which delegates to the engine.

Comment: huh? How does this relate to the question asked?

Comment: Calling a Method on the result of a method (which returns another object) violates the law of demeter. Exception is chaining.

Comment: As long as the return type of `Car.engine` is documented as `Porsche_engine`, there is nothing wrong with making use of that information.

Comment: @ThomasJunk In your example, perhaps, but not in OP's. `"test".upper().replace("T","V")` makes no such violations.

Comment: Better design would define a `start`-method on the `Car` object itself, which delegates to the engine.

Comment: If you look at @Aarons code: person.getBestFriend().getFavoritePizzaTopping(). That is an example of violating LoD.

Comment: @ThomasJunk You're inventing a scenario where method chaining would be bad, then using it to paint all method chaining as bad. That's a strawman argument. Your first sentence is "That is bad code" then you extrapolate from `x.y().z()` that he's created some objects that have knowledge of each other for no reason.

Comment: @AdamSmith Please read my comments carefully. I never said, that chaining _in general_ is bad.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Comments are intended to be temporary post-it notes to answers. Your answer is a strawman argument that does not even answer the question! :D